# VB.NET Select...Case Statement Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I just started using C# and I've got a couple of issues.
Is there any way to code the C# equivalent of the VB.NET Select statement like the following?

```vb
Select Object.Name.ToString()
    Case "Name1"
        'Do something
    Case "Name2"
        'Do something else
    Case Else
        'Do the default action
End Select
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks for the input so far now what about if I hook several controls to one event handler as in the following and I want to perform a slightly different action for each control:

```vb
Private Sub Button_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _
  Handles button1.Click, Button2.Click

    'do a general activity

    Select CType(sender, Button).Name
        Case button1.Name
            'do something
        Case button2.Name
            'do something else
        Case Else
            'do the defalut action
    End Select
End Sub
```

Is there any way of doing the above select statement in C# without having to use nested ifs?

Comment: Update - With C# 7 it is possible to achieve this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have come to find over time that some VB.NET `Select...Case` constructs do not apply in C# and the only way around is to write a lot of ifs.

For instance, in VB.NET, you can write:

```vb
Dim num as Integer = 5

Select Case num
    Case 1 to 10
        'do something

    Case 11 to 20
        'do another thing

    Case Else
        'do the default
End Select
```

But there is no `switch` construct in C# that allows you to do something of this sort. You'll have to code in roundabout like so:

```
int num = 5;

switch (num)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        //do something
        break;
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
    case 14:
    case 15:
    case 16:
    case 17:
    case 18:
    case 19:
    case 20:
        //do something else
        break;
    default:
        //do the default
        break;
}
```

Or if you happen to be working with `Double` or any type which is made up of continuous instead of discrete values, you'll have to use `if`s to get the required action.

Reason? C#'s `switch` requires constants for the various `case`s. This is different from VB.NET's `Select Case` which allows writing ranges.

Comment: It is only round about due to perspective.  For example, in non-numerical cases, the switch statement could be superior.

Comment: With C# 7, it's possible to add condition for range in select statement. Switch has been significantly enhanced in C# 7. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 9):

You'd be looking for the switch statement...

```
switch (Object.Name.ToString())
{
   case  "Name1":
     //Do something
     break;
   default:
     //default
     break;
}
```

Note that the breaks are import, otherwise the program will drop through your cases.  You should be able to find this on almost any C# introduction...

Comment: Note that you don't have to specify the `break` keyword if you throw an Exception or return a value instead.

Comment: true, but just as a preference, I generally like a single return from methods, rather than returning from inside a switch.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.71).aspx) statement.

```
switch (object.Name.ToString()) {
  case "Name1":
    break;
    //Do something 
  case "Name2":
    break;
    //Do something else 
  default:
    break;
   //Do the default action 
}
```

And don't forget that there is a [free online conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) that allows you to convert VB.net to C# and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

**With C# 7, switch has been significantly enhanced**, and it's now possible to apply more conditions within cases, although it's still not as "clean" as the VB version. E.g. you could do something like:

```
switch (examScore)
{
  case int es when es >= 90: grade = "A"; break;
  case int es when es >= 80: grade = "B"; break;
  case int es when es >= 70: grade = "C"; break;
  case int es when es >= 60; grade = "D"; break;
  default: grade = "F"; break;
}
```

**Taken from / References:**

- [C# Switches vs. VB Case Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712749/c-sharp-switches-vs-vb-case-statements)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch